# Replacing Non-Exist Group By Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to run a query like this:

```
select SUM(TONS) as TONS
from MyView 
where Date between '01.01.2017' and '12.31.2017' 
group by DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
order by DATEPART(YEAR, Date) asc
```

The problem is if there is no data on 3rd month it returns 11 rows in total instead of 12. How can I replace missing dates with value of 0?

Comment: Create a calendar table and left-join

Comment: @TimSchmelter, for once I'd do a right join. (I.e `MyView right join calendar`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join the result with months.

```
  SELECT
        C.M YourMonth,
        COALESCE(Result.TONS, 0) AS TONS
    FROM
    (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) C(M) LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            DATEPART(MONTH, T.Date) YourMonth,
            SUM(T.TONS) AS TONS
        FROM    
            MyView  T 
        WHERE Date BETWEEN '01.01.2017' and '12.31.2017'
        GROUP BY    
            DATEPART(MONTH, T.Date)
    ) Result ON C.M = Result.YourMonth
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a calendar table and join to that, or you can use an adhoc calendar like so:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170101';
declare @thrudate date = '20171231';
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,@thrudate)+1)
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
                 cross join n as tenK  cross join n as hundredK
  order by [Date]
)
, cal as (
  select
      [Date]
    , [Month]=month([Date])
    , [Year] =year([Date])
  from dates
)

select
    c.[Year]
  , c.[Month]
  , Tons = sum(v.Tons)
from cal c 
  left join MyView v
    on c.[Date] = v.[Date]
where c.[Date] >= '20170101'
  and c.[Date] <= '20171231'
group by c.[Year], c.[Month]
order by c.[Year], c.[Month]
```

calendar and numbers tables reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops 2- Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

Comment: thank you for the solution. I couldn't think this way which could save hours of work for me

Comment: @TimSchmelter I limited myself to just one of the three pages. I figured if someone was interested enough to click the link, they could find their way to both the first and third page on their own. -- Also, the second page shows the poor performance of a recursive cte, which is a commonly posted alternative to the stacked cte. The recursive cte is not on the third page because it performed so poorly it would have "only served to skew graphs".